# Changing innerHTML doesn't update the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the contents of a table cell to change when I click on it.  Here is the page source:

```js
function cellClick(c) {
  alert(c + " is {" + document.getElementById(c).innerHtml + "}");
  document.getElementById(c).innerHtml = "<b>It Works</b>";
  alert(c + " is now {" + document.getElementById(c).innerHtml + "}");
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="Cell1" onclick='cellClick("Cell1")'>
      Row 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='Cell2' onclick="cellClick('Cell2')">
      Row 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Yes, I am aware that the calls in Cell1 and Cell2 switch the single and double-quotes around; I was testing that as well.

Anyway, the first time I click on a cell, its innerHtml value returns "undefined" (instead of "Row 1" or "Row 2"), and after it is set in the function, it shows the set value; when I click on that cell again, the value previously set by the function is there. However, the value on the page itself never changes.

This has been tried on:

Firefox (64-bit) 65.0.1

IE 11.2791 (which won't show the alerts)

Edge 38.14393

but all of them do the same thing - the value is set, but the page doesn't change.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`

Comment: You set `.innerHtml` which doesn't exist beforehand - you just create this value. Then you read it, so you do get `It works`. But the document doesn't update because it doesn't mean anything in HTML. If you use `innerHTML` it will work.

Comment: ! - that works; I'm a little surprised using "InnerHtml" not only didn't throw some sort of error, but got set and maintained

Comment: That's the loose aspect of Javascript. If you use `document.getElementById(c).myRandomName` it will work too, and actually create this property of the object.

Answer (score 2):

you have written badly innerHtml innerHTML

Comment: You could add a bit more effort in writing your answer. You basically just rewrote my comment. I understand the need for a proper answer so it can be easily read later by other people, but you should have at least explained why there were no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because on innerHTML case.

Secondly it will be tedious to add id to every `td` and pass argument with `onclick`. So you can use `querySelectorAll` then iterate this and add click event listener to it. On click get the innerHTML from the target and alert it

```
function cellClick(c) {
  alert(c + " is {" + document.getElementById(c).innerHTML + "}");

  document.getElementById(c).innerHtml = "<b>It Works</b>";

  alert(c + " is now {" + document.getElementById(c).innerHTML + "}");
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="Cell1" onclick='cellClick("Cell1")'>
      Row 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='Cell2' onclick="cellClick('Cell2')">
      Row 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell) => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let text = e.target.innerHTML.trim();
    alert(text)

  })
})
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell) => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let text = this.innerHTML.trim();
    alert(text)

  })
})
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Without using `e.target`, would it be possible to use `this.innerHTML` if the callback was not an arrow function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the benefits of **event delegation** here.

1. It will create less number of event handlers in memory.
2. It is scalable and will have better performance.

Here is the code snippet for it.

```
function cellClick(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "TD") { //e.target.tagname.toLowerCase() === "td")
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
    e.target.innerHTML = "<b>It Works</b>"
  }
}

<table border="1" onclick='cellClick(event)'>
  <tr>
    <td id="Cell1">
      Row 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='Cell2'>
      Row 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!